# Generic try block in a class for multiple uses around a program (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, try-catch, mysql-connector

Im not sure its possible but i want to use the basic structure of this try block all around my program (to help handle connection problems while retrieving a database), Is there a more efficient way (ie get the block in a class and just pass the fill command to it) that pasting this all over my already messy code?

```
Dim retry As Boolean = True
Dim AllOk As Boolean = False
 While retry
  Try
      Tableadapter.fillbysomequery(dataset)
  Catch exError As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
      Select Case exError.Number
      Case 1042
          retry = CommonRoutines.ShowExceptionDialog(exError.Message, "No connection")
      Case 0
          retry = CommonRoutines.ShowExceptionDialog(exError.Message, "bad login")
      End Select
End Try
End While
If AllOk Then

  'Carry On with the setup stuff
End If
```

the commonroutines.showexptiondialog is a custom exception dialog that returns true or false depending on 'Retry' or Abort.

Several different fill queries in each of 10-15 would just make copying this around the place an absolute mess.

Comment: `"all over my already messy code"` - If the problem is that the code is a mess, clean it up.  For example, this code you're proposing is used specifically around database queries.  So instead of putting it all over your entire codebase, concentrate all of the database queries into re-usable code and then you only need to put this code on that one component.

Comment: Iv been on and off this project for so long, id have never thought of that. 'Its just so crazy it might just work'....I could put all the 'fills' in a class and just call them as needed. ..... *facepalm*